# How do I prevent TextView from stretching out it's parent LinearLayout?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

It seems that a TextView inside a LinearLayout forces that LinearLayout to be larger.  I am trying split my screen top 50% and bottom 50% and also the bottom 50% is split into 3 parts.  So I did my weights 3 (for the top), and then 1, 1, 1 (for the bottom) for a total of 6.

Here is what it looks like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClFPn.jpg

As soon as I take out the TextView inside the first LinearLayout the splits are proper.  The moment I put the TextView inside the top LinearLayout the top LinerLayout gets larger by the amount of the the TextView.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#cccccc"
     android:layout_weight="3">
      <TextView 
      android:text="@string/hello"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>    

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#aa0000"
     android:layout_weight="1">
 </LinearLayout>     

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#00aa00"
     android:layout_weight="1">
 </LinearLayout>     

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#0000cc"
     android:layout_weight="1">
 </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think that with your weight of 1 on the textview, you force the linearlayout to be 3 times the size of the textview height. try removing the textview weight.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the layout for the TextView from:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#cccccc"
     android:layout_weight="3">
```

To:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#cccccc"
     android:layout_weight="1">
```

If that doesnt work, maybe take away "orientation" as well.